# Omiting foreach loop through laravel collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-collection

I'm having a small conditional loop in my application built on `Laravel 5.5`, I'm learning `collections` which seems to be amazing when I know more, currently I'm having following code in my controller:

```
$milestone = Milestone::where('unique_id', $id)
    ->with('project.teams.users.profile')
    ->first();

//  $users = $milestone->project->pluck('teams.users');
$users = [];
foreach ($milestone->project->teams as $team)
{
    foreach($team->users as $user)
        $users[] = $user;
}

return response()->json(['users' => $users], 200);
```

In my code i tried `$users = $milestone->project->pluck('teams.users');` is not giving me proper result, In my model milestone following is relationship:

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team\Project', 'project_id');
}
```

In my Project relationship is:

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Team\Team', 'project_team', 'project_id', 'team_id');
}
```

In my Teams model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

This might by two many to many relationship between `project->teams` and `teams->user` I'm not getting the result.

I want to omit this `foreach` loop through `collection`, Can someone guide me how to implement this through the same, Thanks

Comment: `$users = $milestone->project->pluck('teams.users'); 
$users = [];`
Why did you init `$users` variable and then override it's value with empty array? Do you want to get all users from one project? Can one user be in few teams at the same time?

Comment: @AndriySushchyk Updated the question, Please have a look, this is not giving me proper result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel collections have awesome [`flatten()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-flatten) method.
It flattens a multi-dimensional collection into a single dimension.
So you can use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) and then [`flatten()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-flatten) to get users from all teams as one collection and omit `foreach` loop:

```
$users = $milestone->project->teams->pluck('users')->flatten();
```

It is will return all users from a single project as collection, so you will be able to loop users via [`each()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-each) method:

```
$users->each(function($user){
  //your code here
});
```

Comment: I guess `flatten()`  is the key which I was missing, I did `$users = $milestone->project->teams->pluck('users')->flatten();` and it worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, i just got confused about relationships, Yes, `$users = $milestone->project->teams->pluck('users')->flatten()` is correct.